# php/mysql echoing mysql substrings

Tags: php, mysql, substring

I checked my sql statement in phpadmin and get the results I expect but in my php I cant seem to figure out how to echo the substring from the sql statement

```
#blogDB is a mysqli instance and connected to the database
            $result=$blogDB->query("SELECT id, title, date, SUBSTRING(content,1,200) FROM blog ORDER BY date LIMIT 10");
            while($row=$result->fetch_object())
            {
                $template->content=<<<content
                <h1>{$row->title} - {$row->date}</h1>
                {$row->content}
    content;
                break;
            }
```

Everything is echoing out fine except for `$row->content` which is blank in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the field now is `SUBSTRING(content,1,200)`, you should specify the name you want using `as` like this

```
SELECT id, title, date, SUBSTRING(content,1,200) as content FROM blog...
```

`as` here could be omitted though, so the following will work as well:

```
SELECT id, title, date, SUBSTRING(content,1,200) content FROM blog...
```